# Realtime Performant Tag Search in MySQL or Redis

Tags: mysql, tags, redis, sql-order-by

**Problem Description:**

A tag (tags) can be associated with arbitrary objects through a junction table (tagged_as). For a specific object type (specific_object), select the union or intersection of all of the objects associated with a series of tags, order the results by a numeric column on the object and limit the results for pagination purposes.

**Contrived Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE tags (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE specific_object(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    vote_sum INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE tagged_as(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    tag_id INT NOT NULL,
    content_type_id INT NOT NULL,
    object_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

For the purposes of this example, I am omitting many other columns in the specific_object table.

**Table Row Counts:**

tags: 12,297

tagged_as: 46,642,064

specific_object: 2,444,944

**Naive MySQL Solution:**

```
SELECT
    specific_object.*
FROM
    specific_object
JOIN
    tagged_as
ON
    specific_object.id = tagged_as.object_id
    AND
    tagged_as.content_type_id = <SPECIFIC_OBJECT_CONTENT_TYPE_ID>
WHERE
    tagged_as.tag_id = <TAG_ONE_ID>
    AND
    tagged_as.tag_id = <TAG_TWO_ID>
    ...
ORDER BY specific_object.vote_sum DESC
LIMIT 50
```

The problem with this solution is that MySQL cannot utilize an index to resolve the ORDER BY clause because the "key used to fetch the rows is not the same as the one used in the ORDER BY" (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html). Execution time: 20+ seconds

**Naive Redis Solution:**

```
for each specific object: SET specfic_object:<ID> <ID>
for each tagged as: SADD tag:<TAG ID> specific_object:<ID>

specific_object_ids = SUNION tag:<TAG_ONE_ID> tag:<TAG_TWO_ID> ...
specific_object_ids = SINTER tag:<TAG_ONE_ID> tag:<TAG_TWO_ID> ...

SELECT * FROM specific_object WHERE id IN (<specific_object_ids>) ORDER BY vote_sum DESC
```

The problem with this solution is that the ORDER BY still has to been done by MySQL. Also, a tag could potentially be associated with hundreds of thousands of specific objects which is a lot of data to move around. Execution Time: 20+ seconds for larger tags

**Possible Solutions I Haven't Tried Yet**

*Denormalize*

Perhaps move the vote_sum column into the tagged_as table. Remove the need for the join to do the order by. This might have the same issue as the naive solution.

*Redis Sorted Sets*

```
for each specific object: SET specific_object:<ID> <ID>
for each specific object: SET specific_object_weight:<ID> <VOTE_SUM>
for each tagged as: SADD tag:<TAG_ID> specific_object:<ID>

SINTERSTORE result:<timestamp> <TAG_ONE_ID> <TAG_TWO_ID> ...
SORT result:<timestamp> BY specific_object_weight_* LIMIT 0 50 
specific_object_ids = SMEMBERS result:<timestamp>
DEL result:<timestamp>

SELECT * FROM specific_object WHERE id IN (<specific_object_ids>)
```

Move all of the sorting into Redis. This add extra complexity because now you have to maintain the vote_sum values in Redis as well. Not sure if this would be fast enough.

**Question:**

Are either of the possible solutions viable? Are there other solutions or different technologies that would help? I am open to pretty significant changes to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

When the problem has been performance of a DESC sort, what I've done in the past is to solve the problem is to store the value of `-1*vote_sum` in a separate column, and then ORDER BY that column ASC. I've been able to get MySQL to use an index to do the sort on that column.

You could either store a redundant column (both `vote_sum` and `neg_vote_sum`, or you could just store the negative value, and just multiply it by -1 when you need to return it as a positive value.

But I'm suspicious that the source of your performance issue is the sort operation. How does the performance of the statement compare, as a test, when you do an `ORDER BY vote_sum ASC` ?

Comment: If the performance of the statement with an `ORDER BY vote_sum ASC` is on the same order as an `ORDER BY vote_sum DESC`, then that indicates to me that the performance issue is not with the descending sort.